# How to update bash on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

Just trying to learn bash scripting a little.
My old bash version:

```
Bash version 3.2.53(1)-release...
```

I've updated my bash on mac os x yosemite with homebrew:

```
brew update
brew install bash
```

Then in terminal properties I’ve changed the standard shell path from `/bin/bash` to `/usr/local/bin/bash` (As I understand this is where the homebrew installs the updated bash).

Then I checked the result again (and seems like it's all good):

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
Bash version 4.0.33(0)-release...
```

But when I was trying to write a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Bash version ${BASH_VERSION}..."
for i in {0..10..2}
  do
     echo "Welcome $i times"
 done
```

THE RESULT IS:

```
Bash version 3.2.53(1)-release...
Welcome {0..10..2} times
```

INSTEAD OF:

```
Bash version 4.0.33(0)-release...
Welcome 0 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 8 times
Welcome 10 times
```

Why the Bash version changes back to old one when I'm trying to execute script in the same shell??? This just freaks me out! Please someone explain me what's my problem)))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is in your first line. You have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

which explicitly states that the shell script should be ran with the old `/bin/bash`.
What you *really* want, is this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

to use the new `bash` from `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: weird thing, but it actually didn't work. Still same result((( But I'm sure this is a part of a problem

Comment: Do I need to specify this path somewhere else? In some shell file or something?

Comment: Maybe the environment is set by the calling shell, i.e. the old Bash? How exactly are you calling your script, @Andrew?

Comment: I call my script just like this: sh script.sh

Comment: @Andrew, I suspect that your `sh` is in `/bin`. `brew` maybe didn't make a symlink for `bash` called `sh`. With your `$PATH` set correctly, try starting it like this: `bash script.sh`.

Comment: There u go!!!!! That's how it works! Now solved! Thank you so much!

Comment: For future reference, you should probably use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Answer (score 16):

Install new bash:

```
brew install bash
```

Make this the default shell:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Set the environment in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Using `env` will look for Bash in your `$PATH` and use the first one it encounters. You can see which `bash` it will use by typing `which bash`. If it's seeing `/bin/bash` first, you will need to set your `$PATH` in `~/.bashrc` and `/.bash_profile`.

Comment: If you see "non-standard shell" printed out when using `chsh`, you will need to [update /etc/shells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453236/how-to-set-my-default-shell-on-mac#26321141).

Answer (score 7):

As pjv pointed out, you really should use

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

in your scripts everywhere to be portable. E.g. if you try to run your script with

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

it will fail on most linux systems.